# HasChanges после Merge таблиц C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему HasChanges (у DataSet) выдаёт false после Merge двух таблиц?
В том случае когда заменяются данные по ключу, и по идее, должно сработать изменение DataRowState
На MSDN пишут, что нужно в параметре preserveChanges поставить false - не помогает

Вот маленький пример:

```
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof (string));
    dt1.PrimaryKey = new[] {dt1.Columns["id"]};
    dt1.Rows.Add(1, "name1");
    dt1.Rows.Add(2, "name2");
    ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
    ds.AcceptChanges();

    var dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    dt2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    dt2.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt2.Columns["id"] };
    dt2.Rows.Add(1, "name100");
    dt2.Rows.Add(2, "name200");
    dt2.AcceptChanges();

    dt1.Merge(dt2, false);

    Console.WriteLine(ds.HasChanges());
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Параметр `false` означает НЕ сохранять изменения. Поставьте `true`.

Comment: Потестируйте этот пример и в отладчике посмотрите как будет выглядеть таблица dt1, если при Merge поставить true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких адекватных решений и объяснений не нашёл, решил написать свой Merge :

```
public static void UserMerge(this DataTable dst, DataTable src)
{
   if (dst.PrimaryKey.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("В таблице источнике отсутствует ключ");

    foreach (DataRow row in src.Select())
    {
        var res = GetSearch(row, dst);

        if (res != null)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in src.Columns)
                if (dst.Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                    res[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];
        }
        else
        {
            var newRow = dst.NewRow();
            foreach (DataColumn col in src.Columns)
                if (dst.Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];

            dst.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
}

private static DataRow GetSearch(DataRow row, DataTable dst)
{
    object[] search = new object[dst.PrimaryKey.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < dst.PrimaryKey.Length; ++i)
        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(dst.PrimaryKey[i].ColumnName))
            search[i] = row[dst.PrimaryKey[i].ColumnName];

    return dst.Rows.Find(search);
}
```